# How localised in space versus momentum are particles from the Sun?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, photons, cosmic-rays

In quantum mechanics, unbound states will tend to spread out in space over time according to the Shrodinger equation. So it seems to me there is a degree of freedom for "wild" particles (i.e. those have not been prepared in the lab) as to how much they are spread in space and momentum. So my question is: do we have any knowledge of how disperse "wild" particles (i.e. those which have travelled a long way such as photons from the Sun or cosmic rays) are?

Is there any way to tell, or are we completely unable to extract this knowledge? Fundamentally we can't for an individual particle, but I mean statistically.

I know that the spread must satisfy the Heisenberg uncertainty---my question is what do we know beyond that?

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question. Those who closed it, care to explain why?

Comment: The reason given for closing was "Needs details or clarity" but I'm not sure how to act on that. I thought my description was pretty succinct to be honest. If an editor could clarify I'm happy to fix it.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk interestingly, I don't find anything in here sensible. For instance, how does the origin of a free particle (lab or "wild") play a role in anything? If we're fundamentally unable to tell for an individual particle, how could we gather any information for statistical analysis, regardless of massive vs massless?

Comment: @KyleKanos I interpret the question as simply asking for a characterization of the states in which one expects the particles around us to be, especially with regards to their position and momentum uncertainty. Yes, the question is not phrased perfectly and has some superfluous remarks. But by that standard most questions would have to be closed.

Comment: I removed some of the details and massive/massless distinction to try and make it simpler.

Comment: @KyleKanos My understanding is we can influence how localised particles are that are created in the lab to some extent (e.g. squeezed light used in LIGO), hence the "wild" vs lab distinction.

Comment: We can detect individual particles and accumulate lots of them to construct velocity distribution functions just fine with space plasma instrumentation.  Does that help?